# Laravel distinct() function is not working along get() function

Tags: php, laravel, get, distinct

When I write this

```
$customers_id = Order::where('user_id', $id)->pluck('id');
$customers = OrderItem::whereIn('order_id',$customers_id)->distinct('product_id')->count();
```

it give me correct answer of 2 but when I use get instead of count It gives me all values

Answer (score 1):

I Think this gona going to be the distinct() count

```
$customers = OrderItem::whereIn('order_id',$customers_id)->distinct()->count('producr_id);
```

Comment: Yeah working with it but I want it with get to access all those records which differs from one another

Comment: Then you may use **groupby('column_name')**

Answer (score 1):

Distinct doesn't take arguments: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#select-statements

Your goal is to get the total count distinct by `product_id` only. You have to specify the columns/fields you want to distinct using the `select` method:

```
$customers_id = Order::where('user_id', $id)->pluck('id');
$customers = OrderItem::select('product_id')->whereIn('order_id',$customers_id)->distinct()->count();
```

Comment: Actually my basic goal is to get both the count as well as values of those distinct records.

Comment: You can use @Md Atirur recommendation, use Group By to achieve your goal